# A shortcut for copying an X into a Column B based on data in Column A

Tags: ms-office

Is there a shortcut for placing an X in a column based on the data in another column? For example, if column A has a value "red" can I get Excel to automatically place an X in column B, but NOT if Column A says "blue"?

Comment: @Tetsujin The question was originally tagged with `macOS`. From an OP’s point of view, it might be difficult to choose the appropriate site as Microsoft Office for Mac obviously falls under _third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products._ That said, the question at hand is more of a general Excel question, and any answer is likely to be cross-platform. It [has been suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155488) that [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) is a more appropriate home for these; I tend to concur in this case.

Comment: @Synoli The question was tagged with [tag:mac], not [tag:macos], the former of which is inappropriate and the latter I felt was unnecessary to be added.

Comment: Assuming the OP is using a Mac the question is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: That is actually a general issue with editing someone else's post & tags - by removing the *only* context that had been provided by the OP, the question becomes too genericised. You cannot assume that anyone will read the edit history on a question.

Answer (score 1):

Put a formula into column B (e.g. in cell B1)

```
=if(a1="red";"X";"")
```

You can also stack the `if`s for different values

```
=if(a1="red";"X";if(a1="blue";"Y";"")
```

Comment: OK, so I realize I didn't state my question properly. Dragging the box down to copy is what's taking so long. Is there a way to make that part go faster?

Comment: @MinalBopaiah please edit this into your question then

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in Excel 15.29 on the Mac. I think that's the new
Office 365 version.

In column A I created the following data red, blue, green, red, blue. 
Without "parens," red, not "red" 
In column B I wrote this in B1

```
=IF(A1="red","X","Y")
```

Then dragged it down the B column. This gives me an X in column B for red on that row in column A, and a Y for not red.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074880/chaining-multiple-if-statements-in-excel-to-calculate-work-shifts-from-times?rq=1 gave the syntax for writing if statements in excel.

Comment: OK, so I realize I didn't state my question properly. Dragging the box down to copy is what's taking so long. Is there a way to make that part go faster?